# Populate Table Row with firebase Data Dynamically in Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-tablelayout

So I want to add the data to my table dynamically from the firebase database
This is an Image of my database. I want to fill my table Row with the data from the database
In Product Name in table should come royal and royal glitter and in shade name in table should come name which comes under shade part in database like rb3, silver, gold but gold and silver can't come under royal product name

[image: Firebase Database]

And this is my Java Code

```
package com.example.stockmanagementsystem;



public class PurchaseReport extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> shadeNameList;
ArrayList<String>  productNameList;
ArrayList<String> litreList = new ArrayList<>();
TableLayout tableLayout;
TableRow tableRow;
DatabaseReference databaseReference,databaseReference1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_purchase_report);
    tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.purchase_report_layout);

    //root instance
    databaseReference  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    productNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    shadeNameList= new ArrayList<>();

    productList();

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final int delay = 1000;

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(!productNameList.isEmpty()){

                for (int i=0 ; i<productNameList.size();i++){

                    databaseReference1  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
                            getReference(productNameList.get(i)).child("shade");

                    shadeList();

                    if(!shadeNameList.isEmpty()) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < shadeNameList.size(); j++) {

                            final int jNum = j;
                            tableRow = new TableRow(PurchaseReport.this);

                            TextView v1 = new TextView(PurchaseReport.this);
                            v1.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1));
                            v1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            v1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_row);
                            v1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            v1.setTextSize(18);
                            tableRow.addView(v1);

                            TextView v2 = new TextView(PurchaseReport.this);
                            v2.setText("27/12/2020");
                            v2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            v2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_row);
                            v2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            v2.setTextSize(18);
                            tableRow.addView(v2);

                            TextView v3 = new TextView(PurchaseReport.this);
                            v3.setText(productNameList.get(i));
                            v3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            v3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_row);
                            v3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            v3.setTextSize(18);
                            tableRow.addView(v3);

                            final TextView v4 = new TextView(PurchaseReport.this);

                            databaseReference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                                    if(snapshot.hasChild(shadeNameList.get(jNum))){

                                        v4.setText(shadeNameList.get(jNum));
                                        v4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                                        v4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_row);
                                        v4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                                        v4.setTextSize(18);
                                        Log.i("V4", String.valueOf(v4.getText()));
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                                }
                            });

                            tableRow.addView(v4);

                            TextView v5 = new TextView(PurchaseReport.this);
                            v5.setText("2 Litre");
                            v5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            v5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_row);
                            v5.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            v5.setTextSize(18);
                            tableRow.addView(v5);

                            TextView v6 = new TextView(PurchaseReport.this);
                            v6.setText("2");
                            v6.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            v6.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_row);
                            v6.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            v6.setTextSize(18);
                            tableRow.addView(v6);

                            TextView v7 = new TextView(PurchaseReport.this);
                            v7.setText("12");
                            v7.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            v7.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_row);
                            v7.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            v7.setTextSize(18);
                            tableRow.addView(v7);

                            TextView v8 = new TextView(PurchaseReport.this);
                            v8.setText("123");
                            v8.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                            v8.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_row);
                            v8.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            v8.setTextSize(18);
                            tableRow.addView(v8);
                            tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
                        }
                    }else{

                        handler.postDelayed(this,delay);
                    }

                }

            }else{
                handler.postDelayed(this,delay);
            }
        }
    },delay);

}

private void shadeList() {

    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //adding name to the arrayList
                shadeNameList.add(ds.getKey());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };
    databaseReference1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}

private void productList(){

    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //adding name to the arrayList
                productNameList.add(ds.getKey());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };
    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}

}
```

The Output I Want is this

[image: Desired Output]

Output I am getting

[image: Output]

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic content use RecyclerView and RecyclerViewAdapter with ViewHolder.

Comment: like how any example?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: Still can't understand bro how do I use recyclerView with tableLayout

Comment: Forget about tableLayout. Table layout is not for dynamic content

Comment: So how do i represent data i want it in table format

Comment: What do you mean by table format? What can be done via TableLayout can be achieved by using RecyclerView too

Comment: Like the output I am getting in that photo using table layout can be achieved with the recycler view too

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: Can you provide me any tutorial over it